# I want to have 2 methods in onClick in ReactJs but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call 2 methods at the same time in `onClick` which are `startEdit()` and `showModal()` in `edit` button at the bottom of the code. I did search on google and i wrote what they told me to do but it's not working and it showed me an error! I'm new to ReactJs and also I'm trying to use reactjs with Django.

here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Modal } from "antd";

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  // For Item list from API
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todoList: [],
      activeItem: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        completed: false,
      },
      editing: false,
    };
    this.fetchTasks = this.fetchTasks.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getCookie = this.getCookie.bind(this);
  }

  // function for csrf token just like django documentation told
  getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
      const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchTasks();
  }

  fetchTasks() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/task-list/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>
        this.setState({
          todoList: data,
        })
      );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    console.log("Name:", name);
    console.log("Value:", value);

    this.setState({
      activeItem: {
        ...this.state.activeItem,
        title: value,
      },
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ITEM:", this.state.activeItem);
    // Apply the csrf token just like django documentation told
    let csrftoken = this.getCookie("csrftoken");
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/task-create/";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.activeItem),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.fetchTasks();
        this.setState({
          activeItem: {
            id: null,
            title: "",
            completed: false,
          },
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  startEdit(task) {
    this.setState({
      activeItem: task,
      editing: true,
    });
  }

  // For Modal
  state = { visible: false };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  handleCancel = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    let tasks = this.state.todoList;
    let self = this;

    return (
      <div className="container col-md-6">
        <div className="container mt-5">
          <div className="form-group">
            <button
              onClick={this.showModal}
              id="btn-create-task"
              className="btn mt-4 col-md-12"
            >
              Create Task
            </button>
          </div>
          {/* For Modal */}

          <Modal
            title="Task"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            onOk={this.handleSubmit}
            centered
            footer={[
              <button
                key="Cancel"
                onClick={this.handleCancel}
                className="btn btn-outline-info"
              >
                Cancel
              </button>,
              <button
                id="submit"
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                key="Add"
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-outline-primary"
              >
                Add
              </button>,
            ]}
          >
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.activeItem.title}
                className="form-control col-md-12"
                placeholder="Enter the task"
                type="text"
              />
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
        <div id="task-container">
          <div id="list-wrapper">
            {tasks.map(function (task, index) {
              return (
                <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                  <div id="item-list" className="float-left">
                    <span>{task.title}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="edit-delete-btn">
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {self.startEdit(task); this.showModal;}}
                      className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-dark ml-2">Done</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ListItem;
```

this is the error i got
`Line 186:61:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong: `onClick={() => {self.startEdit(task); this.showModal;}}`
Correct: `onClick={() => {self.startEdit(task); self.showModal();}}`